# How to change path displayed in pytest-html report for each test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-html

I am using pytest-html to generate html report . but in my report complete path is displaying for each test case run.
I want only class name and test case name to be displayed.

In my conftest.py file

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
  pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
  outcome = yield
  report = outcome.get_result()
  report.description = str(item.function.__doc__)
  extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
  if report.when == 'call':
      # always add url to report
      extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url('http://www.example.com/'))
      xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
      if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
          # only add additional html on failure
          extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
      report.extra = extra



@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
  pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
  outcome = yield
  report = outcome.get_result()
  report.description = str(item.function.__doc__)
  extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
  if report.when == 'call':
      # always add url to report
      extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url('http://www.example.com/'))
      xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
      if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
          # only add additional html on failure
          extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<div>Additional HTML</div>'))
      report.extra = extra
```

Actual Result: Complete path is displaying for each test

Expected: Only Class name and testcase name is required

[image: pytest-html report]

Comment: Please let me know if anyone knows this

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `os.environ.get('PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST')`